# Is it possible to secure any file using SQLCipher ?

Tags: android, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

I'm about to develop an Android application where people can protect data (app specific data) in their Android devices. I tried AES 256 algorithm with both CBC and ECB but couldn't achieve the goal. I heard it is possible to do the same using SQLCipher but um blank about SQLCipher. Appreciate if anyone can help me out in learning SQLCipher and develop this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more about SQLCipher [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/), we have a tutorial on integrating the library with an Android application [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/), and a community forum [here](https://discuss.zetetic.net/c/sqlcipher).